# What can cause different levels in communicating vessels?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, water, fluid-statics, flow

I have three small tanks connected by a 6 mm pipe. The pipe fits into an hole made at the bottom side of the tank. Pipes are connected at the junction point using a T-shape connector.

Here a drawing to explain it better:

[image]

The tanks are not airtight. Initially the three tanks are empty.
Then I pour into each one some water from the top hole until they are almost filled up.

In one of them there is another hole at the bottom (not shown in the picture) where is placed a valve. When the valve is closed the actual scenario is exactly like the drawing.

Sometimes the valve opens and let some water to flow out. I noticed that after some time (of course at steady-state - when the valve is closed) the water level in the three tanks is quite different.

I checked the pipe is not clogged.
Actually, the pipes are not so straight like in the picture, but they lay down on the floor, anyway they are always *below* the tanks that are supported with a spacer of about 100 mm above.

Is there anything else that may cause this behavior?

Comment: Downvoting without an explanation does not help me to improve the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the diameter of the pipes, and is there any air at all (in the form of "slugs" of air separated by parcels of water) in those pipes? For small pipe diameters (like clear plastic aquarium tubing) slugs of trapped air in the lines can resist small differences in pressure because of surface tension effects in the tubing, which would affect the heights of water in the three tanks.

You can test this effect by adding a little dishwashing liquid to the water in your system, which will break the surface tension of the water and hence will tend to dislodge any trapped air in the tubes.

Comment: The diameters of the pipes is written in the picture: 6 mm. Good point about the "slugs" of air. I'm going to double check this.